# Circuit for swinging pendulum on clock

Tags: capacitor, clock, repair

I have a large (30”) statue that holds a clock that swings. The pendulum has a small circuit that is powered by a 1.5 V C battery. It stopped swinging even with a new battery.

The circuit has two transistors, a capacitor, a few resistors and a wire coil with a magnet. I have replaced the two transistors. I was advised that it might be the capacitor. I have detailed close-up photos, but I do not know how to upload them. There are a number of us on the internet trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Does the pendulum have a small magnet attached?

Comment: To post a picture file have it available on your system, then in a new Post or during an Edit click the small icon that looks like two up arrows and a dot, (during a hover the icon says "Image"), click that then click "browse", find the file, select it, then click "Add Picture", finally click Review, Post, or Edit.

Comment: @Nedd `two up arrows and a dot` ... mountains and the sun

Comment: @jsotola - YES, though it could be a night scene too.

Comment: It is possibly a simple pulse circuit that puts a pulse onto an electromagnet coil. The electromagnet will pull or push on a piece of metal (or a magnet) that may be attached to the clock pendulum. Consider that the problem could also be mechanical. Test the circuit by passing a piece of steel or a small magnet close to the coil, you might feel it vibrate a bit. The mechanism could be more complicated but a picture would help. If you search for "Clock Pendulum Circuit" you may find a matching example.

Comment: If you search for "electronic clock pendulum" or similar keywords, you should get many hits. Here are a few: https://www.instructables.com/Electromagnetic-Pendulum/  http://maxmcarter.com/pendulum/index.php  https://www.sciencetronics.com/geocities/electronics/projects/pendulum.html